# Ukrainian letters are poorly sorted

Tags: mysql, django, sorting, alphabet

The problem is that when using `order_by()`, Ukrainian letters are incorrectly sorted alphabetically, that is, before "а", "б" is placed "і" and "є".

Answer (score 1):

Changing the column encoding to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` helped me.
PS. Failed to change the encoding of the entire database or table. Only the column.

But later it turned out that this was not enough for me. I need to sort addresses that contain letters and numbers.
In the end I was able to do it the way I needed with [Natsort](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html)

```
from natsort import humansorted
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'uk_UA.UTF-8')
objects = humansorted(objec, key=lambda p: p.address)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the collation of all columns of a table this way:

```
ALTER TABLE <mytable> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

There's no statement to change all tables in one operation. You have to do it one table at a time.